# Devise no session routes on :token_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, omniauth

I use token authentication in Devise (I think; using `omniauth-facebook`). Earlier this week, I had trouble getting my routes without the "token" option. But now, the `token-auth` module is still there, but the routes (`destroy_user_session`, etc.) are gone.

How do I get my session routes with token authentication in Devise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised the problem in issue [1526](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1526), and it was fixed in commit [8b3e0e5](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/8b3e0e52f179e0cbfbdee17fe69876201f79a9a3).